# ¿Qué significa la palabra "sumadora" en esta canción?

Tags: significado, palabras-raras, letras-de-canciones

Escuchando una canción, [cuya letra adjunto](https://www.musixmatch.com/es/letras/Makano/Sumadora), no entendí lo que quiere decir "sumadora", de hecho es una palabra que desconocía, imagino que será latinoamericana.

> No me importa si tu lloras, porque cuando yo sufrí, tu siempre moviste como buena sumadora, pero ahora te toca a tí, la tienes que vivir.

El cantante es Makano, de Panamá y la canción, de 2015, está [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCek9LmJ3-g).

Comment: Parece que "sumadora" no tiene un significado más allá que el de "que suma", se usa para las máquinas calculadoras específicas para hacer sumas. Me intriga más ese uso aparentemente intransitivo del verbo _mover_.

Comment: Exacto, ese mismo significado encontré yo, pero no parece tener ningún sentido en ese contexto, y como indicas, menos con el intransitivo de mover delante. A ver si alguien nos ilumina.

Comment: *Mover* puede ser intransitivo cuando se refiere a un juego con piezas, como el ajedrez: *Te toca mover*.

Comment: @Charlie - ¿Es posible que sea una forma femenina y posiblemente incorrecta de la palabra [sumador](https://es.123rf.com/photo_63658927_v%C3%ADbora-europeo-vipera-berus-del-tambi%C3%A9n-conocido-como-el-sumador-europea-animal-de-la-fauna-.html) que significa unas especies de víbora?

Comment: @walen cierto, vi posible otra explicación.No osbtante, tras el edit, te vuelvo a marcar. Saludos

Comment: ¡Lo mismo digo! Un placer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub><strike>Creo que se refiere a que siempre se comportó de manera fría y calculadora, sin atender a los sentimientos del cantante, pensando solo en su interés. Como una máquina de sumar: como una sumadora.</strike></sub>

<sub>Mi primera interpretación no es del todo correcta. No es un símil con las calculadoras / sumadoras. Quizá fue a partir de ahí que se llegó al significado actual que explico abajo, pero no entro a investigarlo.</sub>

---

Por lo visto, en Panamá "sumadora" tiene un significado específico de "mujer independiente, que se vale por sí misma":

> Al estilo trap, el artista Elvis Coneo José, conocido como Elvis Jey, lanzó al ruedo su nuevo sencillo, titulado “Me provocas”, una canción dedicada **a todas esas chicas que se sustentan por sí solas**. Señaló que el tema salió cuando sus productores le dijeron *“tenemos este instrumental, tírate algo para las guiales”*, pero *“no va dirigido a nadie, ja, ja, ja, está enfocado en las **mujeres sumadoras**, nada más”*.
>   <sub>Fuente: Diario panameño [*Crítica*](https://www.pressreader.com/panama/critica/20170923/281767039408747), 23 de septiembre de 2017.</sub>

> Catalina se desvistió como un bólido de fórmula uno y señores pa’ que, qué monumento, qué espectáculo, una obra de arte hecha carne, piel y huesos. Me puse trucho y me quité la camisa, me desajusté  la correa, bajé la cremallera y la tomé por el cabello, la volteé dejándola de espalda sin soltar la presión en su cabello y embestí primero torpe sin alcanzar a embocar, ella se desesperó, pero se puso colaboradora y **me ayudó guiándome con su mano, una vez dentro empezó a  moverse y  gritar como desquiciada, era una de esas mujeres sumadoras**, +,+,+, eso enloquece a cualquiera.
>   <sub>Fuente: Carlos Polo [*Los tenis panameños*](http://unperdedorconsuerte.blogspot.com/2017/05/los-tenis-panamenos.html), 2006.</sub>

Como apreciación personal, me cuadra bastante que una canción de reguetón use una palabra que significa "mujer independiente y autosuficiente" como si fuera algo malo.
Leyendo artículos sobre la canción y el artista, parece que el artista retuerce el sentido original para convertirlo en "mujer que busca solo su propio interés":

> #### Makano saca tema para “Las Sumadoras”
>
> El artista que no se detiene y sigue escalando hacia la cima es sin duda “Makano”, el cual ya ha lanzado oficialmente su nuevo trabajo musical titulado **“Sumadora”**, canción hecha con su puño y letra, donde el ídolo del reggae romántico le canta a **todas esas mujeres jugadoras que solo buscan interés en una relación**.
>   <sub>Fuente: [LatinOL.com](https://www.latinol.com/vidasocial/makano-saca-tema-para-las-sumadoras/30194.html)</sub>

---

<sub>Apunta nuestro compañero Obie, en un comentario, que en Europa hay un [tipo de serpiente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus) conocido en algunas partes de España como "sumadora" ([aunque en realidad esa especie no existe en España, pero algunas personas la confunden con otra que sí](http://www.serpientepedia.com/serpientes-espana/)) y que quizá sea ese el sentido que le quiere dar el cantante.

Personalmente no me parece verosímil que este artista de Panamá se haya dedicado, lo primero a informarse de los nombres de los reptiles en España, y lo segundo a usarlos en una canción de reguetón arriesgándose a que su público objetivo no entienda a qué se refiere.

Consultando ["sumadora" en Educalingo](https://educalingo.com/es/dic-es/sumadora), no parece que ese uso se dé en América Latina. Por mi parte descarto esta opción.</sub>

Comment: como es común en las canciones de regetton, hay un mensaje sexual oculto con la expresión **"tu siempre moviste como buena sumadora"** que se devela con el aparte del cuento "Los tenis panameños", o sea que mas bien "**sumadora**" es una mujer de mucho líbido.

Comment: En Colombia a expresión "**[sumadora](https://http2.mlstatic.com/sumadora-casio-hr-150tm-plus-envio-gratiswatchito-D_NQ_NP_282811-MLM20637629177_032016-F.jpg)**" se usa para referirse al aparato de escritorio habitualmente con cinta de papel para realizar operaciones aritméticas . Mi comentario fue una deducción por lo que dice el poema en mención y por que en las canciones de reguetón es común las letras con contenido sexual muchas veces de manera velada.

Comment: Ahora quisiera averiguar qué es la etimologia de la palabara sumadora en su significado de "vibora." No puedo imaginar que una serpiente pueda hacer aritmetica.